# loadbalancer service won't redirect to desired pod

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes

I'm playing around with kubernetes and I've set up my environment with 4 deployments:

- [hello](https://hub.docker.com/r/udacity/example-hello/): basic "hello world" service
- [auth](https://hub.docker.com/r/udacity/example-auth/): provides authentication and encryption
- frontend: an nginx reverse proxy which represents a single-point-of-entry from the outside and routes to the accurate pods internally
- [nodehello](https://hub.docker.com/r/thezebra/nodehello/): basic "hello world" service, written in nodejs (this is what I contributed)

For the `hello`, `auth` and `nodehello` deployments I've set up each one internal service.

For the `frontend` deployment I've set up a load-balancer service which would be exposed to the outside world. It uses a config map `nginx-frontend-conf` to redirect to the appropriate pods and has the following contents:

```
upstream hello {
    server hello.default.svc.cluster.local;
}
upstream auth {
    server auth.default.svc.cluster.local;
}
upstream nodehello {
    server nodehello.default.svc.cluster.local;
}          
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/tls/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/tls/key.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello;
    }
    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://auth;
    }
    location /nodehello {
        proxy_pass http://nodehello;
    } 
}
```

When calling the frontend endpoint using `curl -k https://<frontend-external-ip>` I get routed to an available `hello` pod which is the expected behavior.
When calling `https://<frontend-external-ip>/nodehello` however I won't get routed to a `nodehello` pod, but instead to a `hellopod` again.

I suspect the `upstream nodehello` configuration to be the failing part. I'm not sure how service discovery works here, i.e. how the dns name `nodehello.default.svc.cluster.local` would be exposed. I'd appreciate an explanation on how it works and what I did wrong.

**yaml files used**

*deployments/hello.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello
          image: "udacity/example-hello:1.0.0"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: health
              containerPort: 81
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: "10Mi"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 81
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /readiness
              port: 81
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

*deployments/auth.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: "udacity/example-auth:1.0.0"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: health
              containerPort: 81
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: "10Mi"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 81
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /readiness
              port: 81
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

*deployments/frontend.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: "nginx:1.9.14"
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx","-s","quit"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "nginx-frontend-conf"
              mountPath: "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
            - name: "tls-certs"
              mountPath: "/etc/tls"
      volumes:
        - name: "tls-certs"
          secret:
            secretName: "tls-certs"
        - name: "nginx-frontend-conf"
          configMap:
            name: "nginx-frontend-conf"
            items:
              - key: "frontend.conf"
                path: "frontend.conf"
```

*deployments/nodehello.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodehello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodehello 
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nodehello 
          image: "thezebra/nodehello:0.0.2"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: "10Mi"
```

*services/hello.yaml*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "hello"
spec:
  selector:
    app: "hello"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

*services/auth.yaml*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "auth"
spec:
  selector:
    app: "auth"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

*services/frontend.yaml*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "frontend"
spec:
  selector:
    app: "frontend"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: LoadBalancer
```

*services/nodehello.yaml*

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "nodehello"
spec:
  selector:
    app: "nodehello"
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Please provide the yaml files used.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi yaml files added

Answer (score 0):

**This works perfectly :-)**

```
$ curl -s http://frontend/
{"message":"Hello"}
$ curl -s http://frontend/login
authorization failed
$ curl -s http://frontend/nodehello
Hello World!
```

I suspect you might have updated the nginx-frontend-conf when you added /nodehello but have not restarted nginx. Pods won't pickup changed ConfigMaps automatically. Try:

```
kubectl delete pod -l app=frontend
```

Until [versioned ConfigMaps](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368) happen there isn't a nicer solution.